# Consulta sobre estructuras: error: no matching function for call to 'std basic_istream <char>

Tags: c++

Debo realizar un programa el cual registre y luego devuelva el nombre y edad de tres personas distintas, utilizando una estructura u varias estructuras. El programa ya lo realice y termine, solamente seria corregir esos errores para que compile y ejecute.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

struct Persona {
char nombre {20};
int edad;

}persona1,persona2,persona3;


int main()
{
    cout<<"Ingrese su nombre: "<<endl;
    cin.getline(persona1.nombre,20,endl);

    cout<<"Ingrese su edad: "<<endl;
    cin>>persona1.edad;

    cout<<"Ingrese su nombre: "<<endl;
    cin.getline(persona2.nombre,20,endl);

    cout<<"Ingrese su edad: "<<endl;
    cin>>persona2.edad;

    cout<<"Ingrese su nombre: "<<endl;
    cin.getline(persona3.nombre,20,endl);

    cout<<"Ingrese su edad: "<<endl;
    cin>>persona3.edad;

    cout<<"Imprimiento datos"<<endl;
    cout<<"Datos de la persona 1: "<<endl;
    cout<<"Nombre: "<<persona1.nombre<<endl;
    cout<<"Edad: "<<persona1.edad<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Datos de la persona 2 "<<endl;
    cout<<"Nombre: "<<persona2.nombre<<endl;
    cout<<"Edad: "<<persona2.edad<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Datos de la persona 3 "<<endl;
    cout<<"Nombre : "<<persona3.nombre<<endl;
    cout<<"Edad: "<<persona3.edad<<endl;




    return 0;
}
```

Me gustaría saber y entender porque me tira los siguientes errores:

```
16: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_istream<char>::getline(char&, int, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'|
22: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_istream<char>::getline(char&, int, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'|
28: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_istream<char>::getline(char&, int, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'|
```

Comment: `std::endl` no es lo mismo que `\n`. Puedes colocar `\n` en lugar de `endl`, o diretamente omitir el tercer parametro, ya que ese sera un salto de linea automaticamente. [Referencia](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline).

Comment: @Pablochaches Dale, te lo agradezco

Comment: Si estás aprendiendo C++, considera usar los strings de C++ (`std::string`) y `std::getline()`, que trabaja con ellos. La función `getline()` de `std::cin` funciona con strings de C (`char*`).  Por cierto, en tu stuct deberías tener un arreglo `char nombre[20]` o solo podrás guardar un carácter individual. https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/4fx64h/is_there_a_difference_between_cingetline_and/

Comment: @Mateo Entiendo, entiendo. Lo tendre muy en cuenta, muchisimas gracias por tu orientación!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explicación**

> La razón del por qué de los errores, es porque en la estructura estas definiendo el nombre con un `char`, cuando deberías de estar trabajando con `string`.

**Mejoras**

> Acomodé y añadí información a los `cout` de tal manera que fuera agradable de visualizar para el usuario final.

**Solución**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct persona{
    string nombre;
    int edad;
} persona1, persona2, persona3;

int main(){
    cout << "\n\t\tPersona 1" << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\tIngrese el nombre: ";
    cin >> persona1.nombre;
    cout << "\tIngrese la edad: ";
    cin >> persona1.edad;

    cout << "\n\t\tPersona 2" << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\tIngrese el nombre: ";
    cin >> persona2.nombre;
    cout << "\tIngrese la edad: ";
    cin >> persona2.edad;

    cout << "\n\t\tPersona 3" << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\tIngrese el nombre: ";
    cin >> persona3.nombre;
    cout << "\tIngrese la edad: ";
    cin >> persona3.edad;

    cout << "\n\t\tImpresion de datos" << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\n\tDatos de la persona 1: " << endl;
    cout << "\t- Nombre: " << persona1.nombre << endl;
    cout << "\t- Edad: " << persona1.edad << endl;

    cout << "\n\tDatos de la persona 2: " << endl;
    cout << "\t- Nombre: " << persona2.nombre << endl;
    cout << "\t- Edad: " << persona2.edad << endl;

    cout << "\n\tDatos de la persona 3: " << endl;
    cout << "\t- Nombre: " << persona3.nombre << endl;
    cout << "\t- Edad: " << persona3.edad << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

O bien, si también necesitas que sea con funciones y apuntadores, puedes usar esta opción:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct persona{
    string nombre;
    int edad;
} persona1, persona2, persona3;

void cargarPersona(persona &p, int *i);
void mostrarPersona(persona &p, int *i);

int main(){
    int i = 1;
    cargarPersona(persona1, &i);
    cargarPersona(persona2, &i);
    cargarPersona(persona3, &i);

    i = 1;
    mostrarPersona(persona1, &i);
    mostrarPersona(persona2, &i);
    mostrarPersona(persona3, &i);

    return 0;
}

void cargarPersona(persona &p, int *i){
    cout << "\n\t\tPersona " << *i << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\tIngrese el nombre: ";
    cin >> p.nombre;
    cout << "\tIngrese la edad: ";
    cin >> p.edad;
    *i += 1;
}

void mostrarPersona(persona &p, int *i){
    cout << "\n\t\tPersona " << *i << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\tNombre: " << p.nombre << endl;
    cout << "\tEdad: " << p.edad << endl;
    *i += 1;
}
```

Comment: Ufff te lo agradezco muchisimo, gracias por dedicar de tu tiempo para darme un complemento mucho mejor de mi programa. Quisiera también preguntarte si  en lugar de poner solo el nombre, como se podria poder el nombre completo con el apellido (dejando espacios con el enter)

Comment: Claro que también se puede, solo tienes que sustituir `cin >> p.nombre` por `fgets(p.nombre, 20, stdin)`. Sin embargo, tienes que cambiar el tipo de edad a tipo `char` o `string`, debido a que el búfer se vuelve inestable al momento de leer cadenas de texto y enseguida leer un valor de tipo numérico. En caso de que no hagas el cambio de `int` a `char / string`, lo que pasará es que se va a saltar la lectura del nombre de la nueva persona.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por todo